# Expression #29 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column

Tags: mysql, centos

I am using a `GoDaddy VPS server`, after the server setup I can see that they have provided `MySql version 5.7`. I am getting the below error in MySql query, but this query is running perfectly in `MySql 5.6`

I have `root access`.

Error -> `Expression #29 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'sephecom_ecom.v2.secondary_colors' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: "for some reason, I need to downgrade" - What is the reason which can't be solved with settings?

Comment: If you know the answer, please take some time to write, it will help me, thanks

Comment: I don't know an answer other than "Export-Data -> Uninstall-5.7 -> Install-5.6 -> Import Data". But I'm asking why you want to downgrade, because I've never heard a good reason to downgrade.

Comment: try the documentation of mysql there all steps explained inclusive troubleshooting  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/downgrading.html  If you have problems with the steps to take, ask a specific question for it. but i see it like Paul maybe the unkown reasons can be solved.

Comment: Okay, I am editing my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a version problem, it is a configuration problem

The problem is that you have the `only_full_group_by activated`. That means that all your select columns must be either on the GROUP BY or must use an aggregation function (like sum, avg, count, etc). If you want to avoid it you can change it doing

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

If you modify your group by condition, you may get strange results in your query

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, I just want my query to return the exact same result which it is returning in the MySql 5.6 version. My test server is in MySql 5.6 version and everything works perfect, but Live server is with MySql 5.7 and I am getting errors, are you sure that after running the command I will get the exact same result as of MySql 5.6??

Comment: Yes, if your result with Mysql 5.6 was right, then with Mysql 5.7 will be right too, and it will be exactly the same

Comment: Hey, can you please tell me how can I do this? I am using GoDaddy VPS server, and I am logged in as root now through SSH

Comment: The solution worked but I don't know why I face the same issue after every 5-6 days, then I have to go through the same steps to make it work, is there any permanent solution to this?